# Parse a text file, split it into lines, return a list and map into objects

Tags: java, parsing, filereader, streamreader, text-parsing

So I have have 2 types of files, one for level definition and other for blocks structure definition.

I need to parse both of them into list of strings which contains the lines, and go over the list and over each line, split and parse and map them into java objects.

I have no lead how to do it, I have read about java io reader but I do get confused here where and how to use it.

Understanding the content of the level specification of a single level: this will go over the strings, split and parse them, and map them to java objects, resulting in a LevelInformation object.

P.S I already wrote and built the LevelInformation interface(which works if I manually write a level that implements this interface), which contains every thing that is in the text file (level name, velocities,background and etc..)
So basically I just need to parse those texts file and map them into this interface.

```
    public interface LevelInformation {
       int numberOfBalls();
       // The initial velocity of each ball
       // Note that initialBallVelocities().size() == numberOfBalls()
// velocities created by (a,s) format. a = angle, s = speed.
       List<Velocity> initialBallVelocities();
       int paddleSpeed();
       int paddleWidth();
       // the level name will be displayed at the top of the screen.
       String levelName();
       // Returns a sprite with the background of the level
       Sprite getBackground();
       // The Blocks that make up this level, each block contains
       // its size, color and location.
       List<Block> blocks();
       // Number of blocks that should be removed
       // before the level is considered to be "cleared".
       // This number should be <= blocks.size();
       int numberOfBlocksToRemove();
    }
```

**An example of the files:**

*level_definition.txt*

```
START_LEVEL
level_name:Square Moon
ball_velocities:45,500
background:image(background_images/night.jpg)
paddle_speed:650
paddle_width:160
block_definitions:definitions/moon_block_definitions.txt
blocks_start_x:25
blocks_start_y:80
row_height:100
num_blocks:4
START_BLOCKS
--ll--
--ll--
END_BLOCKS
END_LEVEL
```

*block_definitions.txt*

```
    #block definitions
bdef symbol:l width:100 height:100 fill:color(RGB(154,157,84))

#spacers definitions
sdef symbol:- width:30
```

So I need to create a list and get a reader and somehow parse it.
I'll be glad to get some tips, ideas and help for doing this.
Thanks.

```
public class LevelSpecificationReader {

   public List<LevelInformation> fromReader(java.io.Reader reader) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

I think I need to:

- Split the file into lines and make a list of strings out of them.
  Which means each line will get into the list as a string.
- Get each line, and also split it into I don't know what, but in order
  to get info and map in into the needed object. For example:
  level_name: something
        i'll have to get "something" into "level name" in my interface.

This is my failed attempt:

```
public List<LevelInformation> fromReader(java.io.Reader reader) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    String line = bufReader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        listOfLines.add(line);
        line = bufReader.readLine();
    }
    return listOfLines;
}
```

This code brings an error bcause I return a list of string but I need a list of LevelInformation.

Comment: You need to show your code attempt on what you have tried so far for us to provide suggestions

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I have no idea how to write it therefore I have no code attempt. I mean I did try to do something but it's super failed. I'll attach it

Comment: I feel that this is a homework question, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh  I do try to understand the logic of readers and parsing. I asked for guidance and tips. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I need a list of LevelInformation_ Do you have the code for `LevelInformation`? If you do, then [edit] your question and post that code, i.e. the definition of `LevelInformation`. Is it a class? Is it an interface? Once you post the definition of `LevelInformation`, I may be able to show you how to create a `List` of `LevelInformation` objects from the two text files, i.e. _level_definition.txt_ and _block_definitions.txt_

Comment: Is the format of the files fixed? If not I suggest perhaps using a standard format such as json or xml so you can use a parser. That'll save a lot of effort. If it is fixed, then you could learn to use an ANTLR grammar. Again that saves a lot of effort in parsing a file with a specific format.

Comment: @Abra as I said this is an interface. I attached the definition of LevelInformation, take a look.

Comment: @sprinter yes, the format of the files is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, since the code in your question is not a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since it is not complete. Where are the definitions of classes `Block` and `Sprite` and `Velocity`? Well I guessed those and made up minimal definitions for them.

My hope is that the below code will be enough to help you complete your project. It is based on the details you posted including the sample file: *level_definition.txt*

Class `Sprite`

```java
import java.awt.Image;

public class Sprite {
    private Image  image;

    public Sprite(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

class `Velocity`

```java
public class Velocity {
    private int  speed;

    public Velocity(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}
```

Class `LevelDtl` which implements your interface: `LevelInformation`.
Personally, I don't see the need for an interface. I think it should be a class.

```java
public class LevelDtl implements LevelInformation {
    private String  levelName;
    private List<Velocity>  ballVelocities;
    private Sprite  background;
    private int  paddleSpeed;
    private int  paddleWidth;
    private List<Block>  blocks;
    private int  numBlocks;

    @Override
    public int numberOfBalls() {
        return ballVelocities == null ? 0 : ballVelocities.size();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Velocity> initialBallVelocities() {
        return ballVelocities;
    }

    @Override
    public int paddleSpeed() {
        return paddleSpeed;
    }

    @Override
    public int paddleWidth() {
        return paddleWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public String levelName() {
        return levelName;
    }

    @Override
    public Sprite getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Block> blocks() {
        return blocks;
    }

    @Override
    public int numberOfBlocksToRemove() {
        return numBlocks;
    }

    public void setBackground(Sprite bg) {
        background = bg;
    }

    public void setBallVelocities(List<Velocity> velocities) {
        ballVelocities = velocities;
    }

    public void setLevelName(String name) {
        levelName = name;
    }

    public void setPaddleSpeed(int speed) {
        paddleSpeed = speed;
    }

    public void setPaddleWidth(int width) {
        paddleWidth = width;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Level: %s , Paddle: [speed = %d , width = %d]",
                             levelName,
                             paddleSpeed,
                             paddleWidth);
    }
}
```

All the methods with `@Override` annotation are implementations of methods in `LevelInformation` interface. Also, note that method `toString()` is only for debugging purposes since I use it in the final class which is the one you named: `LevelSpecificationReader`. It reads the file *level_definition.txt* line by line, assuming the format shown in your question and builds and configures an instance of class `LevelDtl` which it then adds to a `List`. Finally, the below code prints the contents of the `List`. Of-course, using the sample data you provided in your question, the `List` contains only one element.

```java
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class LevelSpecificationReader {
    private static final String  BACKGROUND = "background:";
    private static final String  BALL_VELOCITIES = "ball_velocities:";
    private static final String  END_BLOCKS = "END_BLOCKS";
    private static final String  END_LEVEL = "END_LEVEL";
    private static final String  IMAGE = "image(";
    private static final String  LEVEL_NAME = "level_name:";
    private static final String  PADDLE_SPEED = "paddle_speed:";
    private static final String  PADDLE_WIDTH = "paddle_width:";
    private static final String  START_BLOCKS = "START_BLOCKS";
    private static final String  START_LEVEL = "START_LEVEL";

    private static void setBackground(LevelDtl level, String data) throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(level, "Null level.");
        if (data != null  &&  !data.isEmpty()) {
            // image(background_images/night.jpg)
            if (data.startsWith(IMAGE)) {
                String path = data.substring(IMAGE.length(), data.length() - 1);
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
                level.setBackground(new Sprite(image));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void setInitialBallVelocities(LevelDtl level, String data) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(level, "Null level.");
        if (data != null  &&  !data.isEmpty()) {
            String[] numbers = data.split(",");
            if (numbers.length > 0) {
                List<Velocity> velocities = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String number : numbers) {
                    try {
                        int speed = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        Velocity velocity = new Velocity(speed);
                        velocities.add(velocity);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException xNUmberFormat) {
                        // Ignore.
                    }
                }
                level.setBallVelocities(velocities);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void setPaddleSpeed(LevelDtl level, String data) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(level, "Null level.");
        if (data != null  &&  !data.isEmpty()) {
            int speed;
            try {
                speed = Integer.parseInt(data);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
                speed = 0;
            }
            level.setPaddleSpeed(speed);
        }
    }

    private static void setPaddleWidth(LevelDtl level, String data) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(level, "Null level.");
        if (data != null  &&  !data.isEmpty()) {
            int width;
            try {
                width = Integer.parseInt(data);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
                width = 0;
            }
            level.setPaddleWidth(width);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start here.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("level_definition.txt");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
               List<LevelInformation> levels = new ArrayList<>();
               LevelDtl level = null;
               String line = br.readLine();
               while (line != null) {
                   if (START_LEVEL.equals(line)) {
                       // End current level.
                       if (level != null) {
                           levels.add(level);
                       }
                       // Start next level.
                       level = new LevelDtl();
                   }
                   else if (line.startsWith(LEVEL_NAME)) {
                       level.setLevelName(line.substring(LEVEL_NAME.length()));
                   }
                   else if (line.startsWith(BALL_VELOCITIES)) {
                       setInitialBallVelocities(level, line.substring(BALL_VELOCITIES.length()));
                   }
                   else if (line.startsWith(BACKGROUND)) {
                       setBackground(level, line.substring(BACKGROUND.length()));
                   }
                   else if (line.startsWith(PADDLE_SPEED)) {
                       setPaddleSpeed(level, line.substring(PADDLE_SPEED.length()));
                   }
                   else if (line.startsWith(PADDLE_WIDTH)) {
                       setPaddleWidth(level, line.substring(PADDLE_WIDTH.length()));
                   }
                   line = br.readLine();
               }
               if (level != null) {
                   levels.add(level);
               }
               System.out.println(levels);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code only handles lines in file *level_definition.txt* up to and including this line:

```
paddle_width:160
```

Good luck with adding code to handle the rest of the contents of the file.

Comment: Wow! It looks amazing! Thank you so much! Although there are still few problems i'm facing but i'll try to figure them by myself.. for example Sprite isn't a class, it's an interface. And why you don't think LevelInformation should be an interface? I think I used it as interface  because in the beginning I created levels by manually inserting the value of the ball velocities, and number of balls and etc.. so it was easier to implement the interface and then just fill up the stats for each level. So now I need to think how to add the img constructor to the Sprite interface.

Comment: @DimaCiun an interface is when you know you may require different implementations. For example, interface [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) has several, different implementations including `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` and `Vector`. From the information in your question, I don't think you will need more than one implementation of interface `LevelInformation`.

Comment: My goal in this code is to get text files, implant them into LevelInformation and make a list of multiple LevelInformation which each one of them describe a level.. And then I would like to send that list to my RunGame function. But first I need to create that list of LevelInformation

Comment: Hey Abra, can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499353/ if you got some time? Your answer here was amazing so I could use your help over there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is to break it into pieces first so that you don't need to worry about all the things at once and focus on parsing the strings. All you need to do is make a constructor that accepts string and then parse it in the constructor

```
public List<LevelInformation> fromReader(java.io.Reader reader) throws IOException {
ArrayList<LevelInformation> listOfLines = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
String line = bufReader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    listOfLines.add(new LevelInformation(line));
    line = bufReader.readLine();
}
return listOfLines;
```

}

```
public class LevelInformation {

       LevelInformation (String text) {
           parseText(text);
       }

       private void parseText(String text) {

           //do something here
       }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I already have though the LevelIformation interface as I posted. Is there any way to "implant" each line as you did here "new LevelInformation(line)" as every object? For example: A line that will include: "level_name: level1" will insert "level1" to the object of "levelName" that is included in the LevelInformation interface?